# Anchor won't work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, hyperlink, anchor, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a problem with internet explorer 11. When you open the website [Letz-meat.nl](http://www.letz-meat.nl) in this version of IE, the links won't work.. There are no JS errors and I can't find the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions.

1. Remove position:relative property of body tag.
2. Add float:left And width:100% (to make full width) to body tag.